# Overwriting Setter&Getter Domain class grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to overwrite getter and setter for domain class. The rational for doing is so that i don't have to redo initialization of this domain class that is in so many places in code.

I have a domain class 'Bank' that used to have one 'address' and it was initialized as follows:
new Bank(address: Address)

Now, i need multiple addresses, so I have a mapping class BankAddress and Bank now have 'addresses' list of BankAddress

To keep initialization the same 'new Bank(address:Address)', i am rewriting 'getAddress' and 'setAddress' like the following:

```
Address getAddress(){
    if(addresses?.size()>0){
        addresses.asList().get(0).getAddress()
    }else{
       return null
    }
}   

void setAddress(Address instance){
    if(addresses?.size()>0){
        addresses*.delete()
        addresses.clear()
    }

    def bankAddress = new BankAddress(address: instance, bank: this, isPrimary: true).save(flush: true)
    addToAddresses(bankAddress)
}
```

Problem is that while my setter is called, the 'instance' parameter of the function is empty making to fail on save - new Bank(address:someAddress):
'AddressId', table 'someDB.Config.BankAddress'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

How come the setter has empty argument? ... I am newbee to groovy & its dynamic nature

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setter you're creating a new `BankAddress` object and then doing a `save(flush:true)`.  One of the properties of your `BankAddress` object is the submitted `Address` object.  If the submitted `Address` object hasn't been saved to the database already, the new `BankAddress` object will try to save a `null` id in its foreign key column in the database, which will fail because the foreign key column is not nullable.

Make sure your submitted `Address` object has already been persisted to the database so it has a primary key id, or delay persisting the new `BankAddress` object until later.

Comment: I removed .save(Flush:true) that would 'delay persisting BankAddress' as well as save flush Address before giving to Bank Address per your recommendation and it works. Thank you for well detailed answer